# how to achieve AddressFamily in winRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I am searching something replacement of System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork. I found HostName but unable to find something that can do like AdressFamily does. Actually, I am converting following code in winRT. I know winRT supports Windows.Networking.Sockets etc. Please describe some solution. 
The code is,

```
if (System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork == _address.AddressFamily &&     _address.AddressFamily == address.AddressFamily)
        {
            long longLocal = BitConverter.ToInt32(_address.GetAddressBytes(), 0);
            long longNetMask = BitConverter.ToInt32(_netmask.GetAddressBytes(), 0);
            long longRemote = BitConverter.ToInt32(address.GetAddressBytes(), 0);
        }
```

_address is also IPAdress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `AddressFamily` does not directly supports WinRT/Metro project so what you need to do is check the `ipAddress` information like this

```
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;

HostName serverHost = new HostName("www.contoso.com");
StreamSocket clientSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();

// Try to connect to the remote host
await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, "http");

var ipAddress = clientSocket.Information.RemoteAddress.DisplayName
```

To check your condition use `_address.Type == HostNameType.Ipv4` then do something but make sure that `GetAddressBytes` do not exist in `HostName` class so for that you need to write your own function to convert an `ipAddress` into bytes.